# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im trying to search if a value exits in an array. Im using ui-select to capture the values, and i create  function to verify if the value exists and all works great but the console show me many times Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

here the select codes used to capture the data

```
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="entrevistainicialModel.personalidad"
                           ng-disabled="false"
                           search-enabled="true"
                           append-to-body="true"
                           class="form-control ">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="Comportamientos">
                        {{$item.comportamiento}}
                    </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="multipleItem.idcomportamiento as multipleItem in datosJson[0].comportamientos | filter: $select.search">
                        {{multipleItem.comportamiento}}
                    </ui-select-choices>
                </ui-select>
```

here is the checkbox code with the function

```
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="check(entrevistainicialModel.personalidad, 1)" value="1"></td>
```

and here it's the function

```
        $scope.check = function (data, n) {
        if (data.indexOf(n) !== -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

all works great! only the console send me many times the error of indexOf

Comment: it's inicialized as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not read indexOf of data it is because data is undefined.

I wanted to say that data have no value in it so it can not have methods like indexOf. You can check  like this:

```
console.log (typeof data);
```

Here, you try to read the type of value in data. If the result is undefined it's mean that data is empty.

So, you have to check if data is not empty (undefined). You can check it like that:

```
$scope.check = function (data, n) {
    if (!data) {return;}      // If data is undefined return.
    if (data.indexOf(n) !== -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `data` contains `undefined`, its because of what you are passing is `undefined` or from somewhere else you are passing nothing to this method. As per your code, I can say `entrevistainicialModel.personalidad` should be initialized with an `array` or `string` or something like tha, which have the `indexOf` method, then you will not get this error **Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined**

Otherwise you should handle the scenario like `(data || []).indexOf(...)`

Comment: I´m initializing entrevistainicialModel as array. Then i use the variable to put json data. And entrevistainicialModel.personalidad it´s another array into entrevistainicialModel

Comment: from where did you initializing? can you add a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: i just had to put this on the function if (!data) {return;} thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, `!data` means its `undefined` or `null` ir `false` equvalent, that meant its not initialized properly (what my guess was). `(data || []).indexOf` will also handle your failure,  however it dosen't matter how you are handling that scenario. Better to not allowing that to happen.